# Saving entity form error - symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

i have error when i try save simple form

Error 
 An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO mEvents (title, desc, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, visibleFrom, visibleTo, timetype, locationName, miejsce) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["sdfsdf", "sd", "2014-01-05 11:11:31", "2014-01-05 11:11:31", "2014-01-05 00:00:00", "2014-01-05 00:00:00", "435", "dfgfg", null]:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, dateTimeStart, dateTimeEnd, visibleFrom, visibleTo, timetype, locationName' at line 1
500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception:

Entity :

```
/**
 * CalendarEvent
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="mEvents", indexes={
@ORM\Index(name="id", columns={"id"})
,@ORM\Index(name="time", columns={"dateTimeStart","dateTimeEnd"})
})
 */
class Event {

    /**
     * @var integer
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $desc;

    /**
     * event start time
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $dateTimeStart;

    /**
     * event end time
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $dateTimeEnd;

    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $visibleFrom;


    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    protected $visibleTo;


    /**
     * 1 jednodniowe, 2wielodniowe, 3 cykliczne, 4 zakresowe
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Column(type="smallint", length=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $timetype;

    /**
     * Nazwa miejsca
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $locationName;

    /**
     * miejsce
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Miejsce",inversedBy="events")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $miejsce;
```

Form :

```
 /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


        $builder
            ->add('title', 'text')
            ->add('desc', 'text')
            ->add('dateTimeStart', 'datetime',array(
                'format' => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'data' => new \DateTime("now")))
            ->add('dateTimeEnd', 'datetime',array(
                'format' => \IntlDateFormatter::SHORT,
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'data' => new \DateTime("now")))
            ->add('visibleFrom', 'date',array(
                'input' => 'datetime',
                'data' => new \DateTime("now")))
            ->add('visibleTo', 'date',array(
            'input' => 'datetime',
            'data' => new \DateTime("now")))
            ->add('timetype', 'text')
            ->add('locationName', 'text')
            //->add('textadres', 'places_autocomplete')

            //->add('mkeywordsId', 'text')

            ->add('save', 'submit')
        ;
    }
```

controller edit action

```
/**
 * @Template
 * @param string $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function EditAddAction($id='')
{




    /**
     * @var $hotel Mmiejsce
     */
    if($id)
        $entity = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository('MiejsceCalendarBundle:Event')
            ->find($id);
    else
        $entity = new Event();



    $form = $this->createForm(new EventType(), $entity);

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();

    }

    return ['form'=>$form->createView()];

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`desc` is a reserved keyword in MySQL. You should then rename this property.

**Edit,**

Even if Doctrine allows you to use keywords by escaping them. I would advice you to rename your property (a best practice) in order to avoid any confusion.

Comment: shouldn't doctrine do this automaticaly? **EDIT**: reserched a little bit and found what i stated in my answer.

Comment: I think better is to rename it properly to avoid any confusion but doctrine allows you to use keywords (by escaping them).

Comment: @MarkusKottländer Ok, I just looked at your answer. +1 for the 'best practice' advice.

Comment: +1 for you for the same reason ;)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use a reserved keyword (desc) as column name you should escape it:

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="`desc`", type="string", nullable=true)
 */
protected $desc;
```

But a best practice would be to not use reserved keywords.

Comment: Yes. But, really: *don't*. You're liable to cause yourself some kind of pain, further down the line. Rename the column.